# How to read from a file a number which has 1 or 2 characters length

Tags: c#

How can I read from a text file, numbers that only consists of one or two characters.
For example:

```
123 32 40 14124 491 1
```

I need to get : `32 40 1`

What I did atm:

```
OpenFileDialog ls = new OpenFileDialog();
int numbersFromFile;
if (ls.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(ls.FileName);
}
```

I'm not sure what to do, I think I need to read all the characters in a string and then to use the substring funcion?

Comment: Down-voting without feedback doesn't add any value.

Comment: But to give feedback with an existing FAQ and clear terms of use doesn't add any value also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
string lines = File.ReadAllText(ls.FileName);
string[] words = lines.Split(new[] {' ', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string result = String.Join(" ", words.Where(w => w.Length < 3));

// result == "32 40 1" given above input
```

Comment: `string lines = string.Join(" ", File.ReadAllText(ls.FileName));` :)))

Comment: @L.B Yeah - stupid (and fixed, though it would've worked too)  ;)

Comment: I don't like placeholder answers much .

Comment: May I ask what's with the character w? it represents each character from the words array?

Comment: [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) is a Linq method, and w is the variable used for each instance type in the collection.  So it's like saying *Where each w in words for those (=>) bit<expression> is true, return a collection of true w*.

Answer (score 0):

```
string numbers = string.Empty;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\so.txt"))
{
    numbers = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

var matches = numbers.Split(' ').Where(s => s.Length == 1 || s.Length == 2);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

`matches` will contain an `IEnumerable<string>` which are the strings that have a length of 1 or 2.  This doesn't check to see if it is a string, though, but the code can easily be changed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the contents into one string and then split out the words to test the length.  Like below

```
            //create the Stream reader object
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("FilePath");
            //open and get the contents put into a string
            String documentText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            //close the reader
            sr.Close();
            //split out the text so we can look at each word
            String[] textStrings = documentText.Split(' ');
            //create a list to hold the results
            List<String> wordList = new List<String>();

            //loop through the words and check the length
            foreach (String word in textStrings)
            {   //if it is less then 3 add to our list
                if (word.Length < 3)
                {
                    wordList.Add(word);
                }
            }


            //...do what you need to with the results in the list
            foreach (String wordMatch in wordList)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are " + wordList.Count.ToString() + " items in the list");
            }
```

Comment: Your first 3 lines of code can be reduced to `var documentText = File.ReadAllText();`

Comment: I am aware of that.  I was going with what the poster had original put out there as to what he was using IE the StreamReader.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do this with a simple regular expression;

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=\ )\d{1,2}(?!\d)";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"123 32 40 14124 491 1"; // read.ReadToEnd();

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

The (?) constructs ensure that you have a space and non-digit surrounding your matches, and the \d{1,2} matches a set of digits either one or two characters long.

Comment: Wouldn't be `\b\d{1,2}\b` for the pattern be easier?

Comment: Actually, yes, that would be much neater!